# Pathwise integral of $W^{-a}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Denote by $\tau(x) := \inf \{t \ge 0, W_t=x\},$ where $W_t$ is a Wiener process started at $W_0 = w_0 > 0$ and

I would like to show that for any $a>1$ it almost surely holds that

$$\int_{0}^{\tau(0)} \frac{1}{W^a_t}dt = \infty.$$

This more or less means to show that $W_t,$ when it approaches zero, it does that (almost surely) at least linearly fast (since for all $a \ge 1,$ $\int_{0+}\frac{1}{y^a} dy=\infty$). I have little idea how to show such a thing for something that is nowhere differentiable.

Maybe one thing one might do is to take a look at time reversal of $W_t$ starting from $\tau(0)$ and try to apply the law of iterated logarithm, which gives bounds for almost all paths of the process near $0$. However, here we'd have to condition on it hitting $w_0$ and also staying positive until it does so. However, this would probably not help anyway, because the $\sqrt{2t\log\log(1/t)}$ does not go to $0$ fast enough (for $t \rightarrow 0+$) for its inverse to diverge.

Are there any Brownian motion path properties that tell us something useful about its behaviour near $\tau(0)$?

EDIT:

The following statement comes from Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas and Shreve (Proposition 3.6.27., Engelbert's 0-1 law):

Let $f:\mathbb R \mapsto [0,\infty]$ be Borel measurable. Then the following is equivalent.

1) $f$ is a locally integrable function.

2) $\mathbb{P}^0[\int_0^t f(W_t) < \infty, 0 \le t < \infty]>0$

3) $\mathbb{P}^0[\int_0^t f(W_t) < \infty, 0 \le t < \infty]=1$

This is not exactly what I want. First of all, I am not starting from $0$, but from a positive point. That is not really a big deal though. What is more troublesome is that I do not integrate to a constant time $t$, or at least an independent stopping time, but to something that heavily influences the path. So even though I have a nice uniform result for the constant times, it is not as nice with the stopping time I have. I am now trying to fit the result to what I have, but I'm a bit stuck. My $f$ can be seen as $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^a},$ where $a$ is positive and therefore it is not locally integrable. Still, there is the problem with the stopping time.

Comment: Why do you expect/think that this holds true? By the time inversal property of Brownian motion, the behavior when $W_t$ approaches zero is exactly the same as the behavior of a Brownian motion started at zero for small times. Since the law of iterated logarithm states that this behavior is $\sqrt{2t \log \log 1/t}$, we cannot expect that the integral diverges. (This question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783518/law-of-iterated-logarithms-for-bm might be of interest.)

Comment: Is time reversal true even for stopping time? For example, any Brownian motion is regular, in the sense that it revisits the starting point infinitely often near $t = 0$. But if we consider the time reversal at $\tau(0)$, it instantly leaves upward from $0$. So they should have different law.

Comment: sos440: Yes, this is why I am a bit worried.

Comment: saz: There is a similar statement that holds true (with a relatively simple proof based on the brownian local time)...I added it to my question. Also, the LIL just gives you an upper bound for the behaviour of $W$, it does not tell you that is it exactly like that. If it actually converged at the speed of the loglog bound, it would be too slow, you are right. But that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: It now seems that it would be enough for me to prove this for $a \ge 2$. For $a > 2$, this should be easily proven by applying the law of iterated logarithm and the fact that the time-reversal of a Brownian Motion has the same distribution as the original. Sadly, the case of $a=2$ is actually the most crucial one...but for this, the $W^{-a}$ approaches 0 still too fast to be of any use.